# Pyxll:TypeError list indices must be integers or slices,not float

Tags: python, typeerror, pyxll

In excel in cell A1 I have a simple text Hello World.

I write simple UDF function in Pyxll:

```
from pyxll import xl_func

@xl_func
def get_txt(txt,delimiter,ind):
    l=txt.split(delimiter)
    return l[ind]
```

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEoUN.jpg)

When i call this function in excel =get_txt(A1;" ";0) i get error:
**TypeError list indices must be integers or slices,not float**

But in python this code works fine.
Please help how fix this error.
Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, solution found:
need to add annotation

```
from pyxll import xl_func

@xl_func
def get_txt(txt:str,delimiter:str,ind:int)->str:
    l=txt.split(delimiter)
    return l[ind]
```

but in xlwings it doesn't work((